# Как картинку сделать фоном окна?

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как картинку сделать фоном окна в Delphi?

Comment: @Маргарита, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.
Вбейте собственный вопрос в гугл.

Comment: Алексей,я не прошу кого-то что-то делать за меня. Да,я студентка,делала курсовую. Но я ее уже почти закончила и сдала (за неделю). На выполнение требований к ней у меня ушло часа 3 и мне хватило собственных знаний. Просто есть выражение "лучшее-враг хорошего" и когда все сдано, есть возможность покуралесить в свое удовольствие. И вот мне стало интересно, как сделать то,чего я не умею. Это чистый интерес. По-моему,правила форума я не нарушала ничем. Могу текст курсовой выложить, чтобы отпали сомнения в моей полной тупости и попытке решить свой проблемы за счет более грамотных людей.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот так можно

```
var
    bitmap:Tbitmap;
begin
    bitmap:=Tbitmap.Create;
    bitmap.LoadFromFile('c:\1.bmp');// Здесь путь к файлу
    form1.Canvas.CopyRect(rect(0,0,form1.Width,form1.Height),bitmap.Canvas,rect(0,0,bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height));
    bitmap.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я предполагала,что через Canvas надо делать. Проект не нужен,этого хватит,чтобы оттолкнуться и развить мысль. Просто направление хотела уточнить